# PHP post data to user custom url without as an array

Tags: php

simply i can use this below code to post any result as an array with message as json format for example:

```
array('result'=>"{'code':'101', 'message':'ok!!'}")
```

this format result for my users is not standard and they like to get the result only as an json format for example:

```
{'code':'101', 'message':'ok!!'}
```

I can't find other code to instead of my code for return the result

My code:

```
function redirect_to_customer($result = [], $redirect_url = "")
{
    $html = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head></head>
                <body onload="closethisasap();">
                <form name="redirectpost" method="POST" action="' . $redirect_url . '">
        ';
    if (!is_null($result)) {
        $result = json_encode($result,true);
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="result" value="' . str_replace('"', "'", $result) . '"> ';
    }

    $html .= "
    </form>
    </body>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        function closethisasap() {
            document.forms[\"redirectpost\"].submit();
        }
    </script>
    </html>";

    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Are You Familiar with jQuery ?

Comment: @Ahsan i try post only json format not array to user. thats is webservice request

Comment: @CodeZilla please read carefully my code and question sir !!

Comment: @mahdipishguy Sorry my bad. You can use cURL to post a data to url without form. here is an example. http://devzone.co.in/post-data-using-curl-in-php-a-simple-example/

Comment: @CodeZilla please let me to test that

Comment: @CodeZilla with `cUrl` location dont redirect to user redirect_url.

Comment: @mahdipishguy you can redirect the user after curl  request is completed by using `header('location: '.$redirect_url);exit();`.

Comment: @CodeZilla I get this error: `The page isn't redirecting properly`

Comment: This can be caused due to redirection in loop. can you share your code I can have a look at that. Please provide the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can post an array in a html form, by using brackets in the field's name:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="result[]" value="'code':'101'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="result[]" value="'message':'ok!!'" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Will output:**

```
array(1) 
  ["result"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "'code':'101'"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "'message':'ok!!'"
  }
}
```